# Why "sudo -s" change to root user without asking for password

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, sudo

When I type in "sudo -s" in the command line, I changed to root user without typing in any passwords. I'm confused why this happened. From my understanding. Can someone explain that?

Comment: Did you run a sudo command within the last 5 minutes? Sudo lets you run multiple commands without entering the password every time. This is, of course, configurable (`visudo`).

Comment: You normally have to type the password once; you are then allowed to connect using that password for a few minutes (I expect the period is configurable).  Note that you type your own password, not `root`'s password.  This means that the `root` password can be strictly controlled, but administrative users can do operations requiring root privilege because `sudo` authorizes them to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this/previous session you was root also.

lets say if you entered as root, `sudo -s` - no action. Or you created session, entered as root,  closed for example ssh connection and entered once more (during 5 min), the result, you still stay as root

Comment: +1 I second this. This is the only way I see sudo working without a password. That, or the `sudoers` file has been modified.